# WPF Combobox selection in Windows 8 with mouse cursor

Tags: wpf, combobox, windows-8

I have a wpf app with a regular combobox. 
When testing this app in Windows 8 RP the combobox is behaving a bit odd.

To select an item I have to move the mouse cursor over the text on that item, 
otherwise the control will not mark it with the hover style and if I click it will not registrate it as a valid click on that item. The combobox will close and select the last one that was selected.

The full row on a combobox item should be selectable, not just the text area.
I haven't done any styling or templating at all on the combobox. Just bind it to a data source.

Anyone seen this behaviour before and know what to do?

It is only in Windows 8, in Windows 7 it is working just like it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: This bug was actually fixed by Microsoft between the last Release Preview version of Windows 8 and RTM.  I can't believe it!!!**

--Original answer:

I've got the same problem on Windows 8 RP.  Until it's fixed or there's a better workaround, I intend to force the Aero theme by executing the following on application startup when Windows 8 is detected:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("PresentationFramework.Aero;V4.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Insert(0, Application.LoadComponent(uri) as ResourceDictionary);
```

I'm not sure how correct/good this is, but it got me back to working comboboxes and appears to have negated the weak Metro styling present in all controls except for buttons and textboxes, for some reason.

I use Insert here instead of Add to preserve my custom styling of various controls.

Comment: Yes, it seems that it is fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.